# VS Code Python Interpreter Still shows 3.8.6 even though the 3.9 update came out?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, updates, interpreter, python-3.9

It appears that I'm still using Python 3.8.6 even though the Microsoft store version of python says the 3.9 update was released and that I have it installed. How can I use the new version from the Microsoft store? I tried reinstalling multiple times and tried installing from the python website before but I ran into a problem where I couldn't install libraries for some reason.

[image: No other interpreter option is shown:]

Comment: Go to Microsoft Store are uninstall all pythons, then reinstall python 3.9

Comment: I tried that but it still tells me I'm on 3.8.6

Answer (score 1):

to fix this, do the following

1. Go to [Python's official website](https://python.org), download the latest version of python 3.9.
2. delete the `.vscode` folder and restart your editor.
3. select your python version in the drop down menu as 3.9.

**Warning: python 3.9 will not work on Windows 7 and below**

Answer (score 0):

I tried this process in my computer:

1. Download [python3.9](https://www.python.org/downloads/).  I checked "`Add Python3.9 to PATH`" before installation:

   [image]

   It automatically adds `python3.9` to the environment variables of the system:

   [image]
2. Open the python interpreter in VSCode:

   [image]

It is recommended that you enter "`where python`" in the cmd window to check whether `python3.9` is available. In addition, please use the latest version of [VSCode](https://code.visualstudio.com/) and [Python extensions](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.python).(2020.10.332292344)

[image]

Comment: or `where.exe` on powershell